# He dies when he is

Tags: verbs, tenses

Teaching English for adults we were reading a story. In the story of a man appears this sentence **" He dies when he is 102 years old"** An ESL adult asked me: Shouldn't be that sentence in the past,... when he **was** 102? I said No, it's OK the way it is;but I struggled to give him the reason. Could somebody help?

There are some questions about the use of *would* with the historical present on this site:

- ["Paul would later transfer to McKinley High and join Kevin and Winnie."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61129/paul-would-later-transfer-to-mckinley-high-and-join-kevin-and-winnie)
- [Using “would” when narrating a story in simple present [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61132/using-would-when-narrating-a-story-in-simple-present)

But this question is about why it is possible to use the present simple in this particular example. It does not ask about the use of *would* with the present simple.

I wasn't born here so English is my second language too!!!

Comment: Normally, totally out of context, and in most real contexts, it should be "...died...was...". But in the context of the story there may be very particular circumstances where dies/was works.

Answer (score 4):

Narrative is most often in the past tense, but it is nevertheless quite common to use the *historic (or narrative) present tense*.

When using the historic present, the viewpoint moves along with the events described, so *is* is the only choice here. You could say (in a present-tense narrative) *He died when he was 102 years old*, and that would locate the death in the past relative to the current narrative moment (eg perhaps the narrator is looking at a picture of his father); but to change the tense in the middle of that sentence would be incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

You might use this , if you were discussing a book in which one of the characters dies, and you are speaking from the perspective that he is not dead yet , but you know he will die !

You would not use this sentence in real-life, unless you were a crazy dictator who had decided to execute at some point in the future (on that persons 102nd birthday) .

regards !

Comment: No; Colin's explanation is the correct one. Tenses aren't always used logically.